# How can I capture the output of the "git fsck" command in a python script on Windows?

Tags: python, git

I tried this ...

os.chdir(repo_path)

f = open("blah.txt", "w")
subprocess.call(["git", "fsck"], stdout=f, stderr=f)

...

Couldn't find any way to do it with GitPython module either.

If I change "fsck" to "status" I see output in blah.txt but I can't see anything if I use "fsck". The output I get from the terminal when running the git command directly is ...

"Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done."

Thanks

Comment: The progress indicator from `git fsck` goes to stderr, which you're capturing. The problem here is more general than that: Git's progress indicators are in general suppressed if the output device is not a terminal (does not satisfy the `isatty` function in C). This is intentional: programs that read other programs' output generally don't need progress indicators. Just don't *expect* them and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh okay, so if the command had returned an error I would be able to read that in stderr minus the progress indicator info shown above? I'll try deleting some random thing in the repo to trigger an error from fsck and see what I get. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

torek had it right. Any errors or problems coming from git fsck are showing up in stderr or stdout. If there are no problems then there is no output. I was mistaking the progress indicator as a report of success but no output is what I should have been testing for.